# Change account API when committing a notebook to Jovian?

Tags: api

is there any way to change the account API to commit to another account?

Even when I uninstall Jovian, and then install it again, the commit function still links to the previous Jovian account.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to this. Thanks to a friend from an online course. The suggestion below really works - the "jovian.configure()" function.

> "You can execute the re-configure function, so that Jovian will ask
> you to input API key again, here you need to submit your second
> accounts API key.
>
> jovian.configure()
>
> If this still not working, you can reopen the jupiter notebook session
> once again and configure Jovian account."

Furthermore, to prevent the notebook to be published everytime it is committed, we can change the setting in "General Settings" on Jovian:
[Default Notebook Privacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsMoM.png)